# Not able to install nltk data on django app on elastic beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, nltk, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using nltk_tokenize in an django app . To do the same I need to do nltk data download so that I can use it for stemming . I am deploying the django app on cloud through Elastic beanstalk .

Right now I have included

```
nltk.download('punkt')
```

in the my views so that the required data gets downloaded . But I am getting following error

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/wsgi/nltk_data'
```

What is the correct way to do so?

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure what nltk_tokenize is really, but your app is running on Elastic Beanstalk by wsgi user. This is a user that doesn't have a home directory. You need to specify the path to somewhere that exists like /opt/python/current/app (your app's directory in Elastic beanstalk), or /tmp/ or what now would make sense.

Edit: Corrected directory after comment.

Comment: Worth mentioning, Elastic Beanstalk's app directory is /opt/python/current/app, not the other way around. Also, if you download to there, it'll be wiped on your next deployment.

Comment: Also it is important to add the new path to nltk path: nltk.data.path.append( download_dir )

Answer (score 2):

I achieved it by adding `nltk_data` files to my s3 bucket and then copying them from my s3 bucket to server by creating an eb extensions file with following command:

```
commands:
  01_copy_nltk_data:
    command: aws s3 cp s3://my_s3_bucket/nltk_data /usr/local/share/nltk_data --recursive
```

After that, I added `NLTK_DATA` environment variable in my python script and pointed it to the location of `nltk_data` on server.

`os.environ['NLTK_DATA'] = "/usr/local/share/nltk_data"`

Comment: After doing this deployments failed. In health page I got an error stating that "Application update failed at 2019-05-27T15:56:17Z with exit status 1 and error: command 01_copy_nltk_data in .ebextensions/s3.config failed.

fatal error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied."

Answer (score 0):

You can use this block code:

```
import nltk
try:
    nltk.download('punkt', download_dir='/opt/python/current/app')
except:
    nltk.download('punkt')
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer as SIA
```

What we are trying to do here is import nltk and then we are trying to download 'punkt' in app directory of Elastic beanstalk app since this is a wsgi app, so wsgi user doesn't have access to home directory.